# Can we transfer model trained on one PC to another PC

Tags: keras, python-3.6, machine-learning-model

I have trained cnn model on MAC using tenserflow and keras.Can I move this trained model to another PC which has windows? If Yes, then can we use that trained model for prediction whithout having tenserflow , keras installed on it?

Answer (score -1):

You can save your trained model with `save()` method.  To load again your trained model you can use the function provided by the library:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
del model  # deletes the existing model

# returns a compiled model
# identical to the previous one
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

As shown in the documentation: [Documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)

To the question about executing your model without keras or tensorflow installed on it, the short answer is no. The long answer is yes, but you will have to use any other library or implement by yourself a function which takes the model trained weights and architecture and do a common feedforward to return the result.